# Reference for slokam "aho yashode tava balakoyam"

Tags: shloka, reference-request, source

Can someone please give a reference to the following slokam?

> aho yashode tava balakoyam grude gruhe

(39:23 in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8mZCRPxDXng) video)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be from the *Rukminisha Vijaya*, which is a Vaishnava work composed by the saint Vadiraja Thirtha in the 16th century. There's an online version linked [here](https://sites.google.com/site/harshalarajesh/rukminishavijaya), and this specific verse is [here](https://sites.google.com/site/harshalarajesh/rukminishavijaya-canto3).

> aho yashodhe thava bAlakOyam gRuhe gRuhEthyuShNamapIha dhugDham
>
> pibanna thApam labhathe kadhApi kimasya vavathrE jalashashirAsthe
>
> [Part 3- line 53]

There's also [this](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Rukmi%E1%B9%87%C4%AB%C5%9Bavijaya%E1%B8%A5/MekJAAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B%20%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%22&dq=%22%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%8B%20%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%B6%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%87%22&printsec=frontcover) snippet, which is written in Hindi. You can only see the bottom half of the letters, but it looks to be the same line. All the online versions of the Rukminisha Vijaya include this line, I linked the one above because you don't have to download any pdf to see it.

Since Vadiraja Tirtha himself was the one who wrote the poems (rather than merely compiled them), it feels safe to say that it was he who wrote the verse too.

Hope that this is helpful! Let me know if you want a translation :)

Comment: Can I ask how did you search this?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - I used [this](https://books.google.com/advanced_book_search) tool, which allows you to search for a word/phrase through a database of books. I didn't get any results for 'aho yashode,' so I searched for 'अहो यशोदे,' which gave me the snippet I linked in my answer. Then I just searched the web for an online version of the text and found the full verse.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying for anotherslokam in the end at 1:08:18 .. aneena tad padmabhavo mrudangam.. It seem to be some stuti by nagapatni.. If you don't mind, can you please help me with this

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - I will try to do so. It may take a few days, though, sorry.

Comment: please take your time.. I am getting absolutely no result from the search.. may be I am not using correct tricks..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik - I'm stumped! I can not find that verse anywhere. If you post a new question, someone else might be able to find the reference. But I haven't been able to, sorry.